# Excel Multiple Vlookup's based on cell values with sums

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to carry out 2 different vlookups, based on 2 different cell values, then divide the resulting figure by a cell value. 
I have been playing around with this for a while, I am also using helper cells, but I am still struggling to get it to function correctly.

[image: Spread Sheet Example]

Formula I am trying to get to work.

```
=IF(J2="Portrait",ROUNDDOWN(VLOOKUP("Middle",B:C,2,FALSE)/$J$5,0),ROUNDDOWN(VLOOKUP("Middle",B1:C4,2,FALSE)/K$5,0))
```

The cell value for J2 will either be Portrait or Landscape.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks, 
Steve

Comment: What error are you getting? Why does the formula in your picture not match what you have in your question?

Comment: There are no errors, I am just not getting the answer I wanted. For example the formula attached gives me the results for Bottom, instead middle. I have 3 formulas across 3 cells, which operate the same, but look at Top, Middle and Bottom